# Factor levels out of order in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, factors

First time asking a question here and very new to R, so please bear with me if I format/phrase something incorrectly. Thanks in advance for your help!

I have multiple columns stored as factors in my dataframe. However, after running a code chunk of dplyr functions with pipes, the tibble output is not retaining the factor levels from the dataframe. The data is out of order.

Here are the factor levels (I eliminated some of the preceding code because it's long):

```
...
POST_600_WOBA_GRADE = factor(POST_600_WOBA_GRADE, levels = c("Elite", "Great", "Good", "Average", "Below Average", "Poor", "Awful", "DNQ")))
```

When I run this to confirm, the correct levels show:

```
levels(all_batter_career_data_by_ID$POST_600_WOBA_GRADE)
[1] "Elite"         "Great"         "Good"          "Average"       "Below Average"
[6] "Poor"          "Awful"         "DNQ"
```

However, when I run this below, DNQ and Awful get flipped. DNQ (Did Not Qualify) should be on the far right.

```
all_batter_career_data_by_ID %>%
  filter(BAT_DEBUT < "2015-01-01") %>%
  group_by(FIRST_600_WOBA_GRADE, POST_600_WOBA_GRADE) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = POST_600_WOBA_GRADE, values_from = n)

# A tibble: 8 × 9
# Groups:   FIRST_600_WOBA_GRADE [8]
  FIRST_600_WOBA_GRADE Elite Great  Good Average `Below Average`  Poor   DNQ Awful
  <fct>                <int> <int> <int>   <int>           <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Elite                    1     1     4       1              NA    NA    NA    NA
2 Great                    5     9    14       7               3     1     8    NA
3 Good                     1    21    62      56              20    12    44     1
4 Average                  1    10    45      77              29    29    78     6
5 Below Average           NA     5    24      36              14    26    56     7
6 Poor                    NA     5    22      35              14    33    94    20
7 Awful                   NA     1     7      21               9    38   132    22
8 DNQ                     NA    NA    NA      NA              NA    NA  1126    NA
```

I am running the exact same code for another variable with the same factor levels, and the tibble is in the correct order, so I'm not sure why this one is flipped. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Your code looks good and I am unable to recreate the problem. You could try double checking that you saved it correctly (DNQ comes after Awful in the levels), or start a new session and try to run it with a clean env. Otherwise, you could create a minimal reproducible example with a toy dataset that has the same problem you ran into so we can troubleshoot easier.

Comment: Otherwise a quick and fix would be to rearrange the columns ```data %>% select(FIRST_600_WOBA_GRADE, Elite, Great, Good, Average, `Below Average`, Poor, Aweful, DNQ)```

Comment: Try to add `names_sort = TRUE` into `pivot_wider`

Comment: @DarrenTsai names_sort = TRUE worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is going on, here's some sample data:

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
  "first_grade" = "Elite",
  "second_grade" = c("Elite", "Great", "Good", "Average", "Below Average", "Poor", "Awful", "DNQ") |> factor(levels = c("Elite", "Great", "Good", "Average", "Below Average", "Poor", "Awful", "DNQ")),
  "n" = sample(1:100, 8, replace = TRUE))

  first_grade  second_grade  n
1       Elite         Elite 14
2       Elite         Great 68
3       Elite          Good 39
4       Elite       Average  1
5       Elite Below Average 34
6       Elite          Poor 87
7       Elite         Awful 43
8       Elite           DNQ 14
```

Pivoting this data wider gives us the right answer, but once we randomly sort the rows, we get the wrong answer:

```
df <- df[sample(1:8, 8),]  

tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = "second_grade", values_from = "n")

# A tibble: 1 × 9
  first_grade Great  Good Awful Elite `Below Average` Average   DNQ  Poor
  <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int>           <int>   <int> <int> <int>
1 Elite          68    39    43    14              34       1    14    87
```

As Darren has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77520767/factor-levels-out-of-order-in-tibble/77521056#comment136665327_77520767), the solution is to use the `names_sort = TRUE` argument for `pivot_wider()` (sorting the column you're wanting to pivot wider would work too):

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = "second_grade", values_from = "n", names_sort = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 9
  first_grade Elite Great  Good Average `Below Average`  Poor Awful   DNQ
  <chr>       <int> <int> <int>   <int>           <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Elite          14    68    39       1              34    87    43    14
```

Comment: names_sort = TRUE works perfectly. Thanks for your helpful and thorough explanation, Mark. Much appreciated!